# Accessing model attributes results in Self not defined error

Tags: python, django

Can anyone help me understand why I am receiving the error `self is not defined` while accessing a class attribute? Thanks for your help

```
    class Receipt(models.Model):
        ""
        receipt_id = models.AutoField(
            primary_key=True,
            db_comment=""
        )

        store_name = models.TextField(
            max_length=255,
            default="Unidentified",
            db_comment=""
        )

        total_amt = models.DecimalField(
            max_digits=6,
            decimal_places=2,
            default=0.00,
            db_comment=""
        )

        def create_from_document(document):
            ""
            if (document is None):
                 return False
            
            self.store_name = document.store_name
            self.total_amt = document.total_amt
                 
            self.save()

            return self
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to pass `self` to the class method. Add it before `document` as it will be passed as the first argument:

```
    def create_from_document(self, document):
        if (document is None):
             return False

        self.store_name = document.store_name
        self.total_amt = document.total_amt

        self.save()

        return self
```

Comment: Thanks. I assumed self was automatically available - a hangover from my days with OOP in other languages